# Use Simulink work Space variable from a C Function block

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink

As you might know Simulink offers a block called C Function block which allows us to call legacy C code on the Simulink environment(See [C-Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/cfunction.html)).

This block has an option which allows us to declare input, output, parameter and constant parameter that further be used inside the C function, but I want to know if there is any way to call Simulink Workspace parameters (e.g. Simulink parameters defined in the base workspace) to be called inside the C function blocks.

Comment: You can pass the simulink parameters as arguments to the c functions. What do you mean by "call" a parameter?

Comment: just looking for some API to be used to get the parameter value by its name from the base work space like: getBaseParam("SomeVariable");

Comment: I think if you create a block parameter on the C Caller function block, you can specify the name of a workspace variable there.

Comment: I have tried this before but it will create local scope variable with that name and there is no relation between this type of variables with the workspace variable.